# Stay on same tab after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tabs

I am using Samson O's very nice [Easy Responsive Tabs to Accordion plugin](https://github.com/samsono/Easy-Responsive-Tabs-to-Accordion) on an ASP.NET page.  On Tab 2 I have a Search button that when clicked executes some code in a code-behind and returns the search results to the page.  Everything works except that the page goes back to the first tab when it's finished running the code in the code-behind.  I want it to stay on Tab 2.  How can I achieve this?

I have tried calling a JavaScript function to simulate the click of Tab 2 (`$('#mycharities').click();`) from the OnClientClick event of the Search button and also as the last thing on the Search button click event in the code-behind.  Both options run the JavaScript but the page still goes back to the first tab once finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question lies in the script for this plugin :

```
 //Active correct tab
            $($respTabs.find('.resp-tab-item.' + options.tabidentify)[tabNum]).addClass('resp-tab-                     active').css({
                'background-color': options.activetab_bg,
                'border-color': options.active_border_color
            });
```

If you notice it takes [tabNum] to set the active tab. So you need to figure out the last selected tab num and in your custom javascript function that you need to set the appropiate css class to that tab. Then u will have it selected after the postback.

Best yet try to submit using AJax. It easy and you can avoid hassles.

Comment: Hey thanks so much qamar - I used Ajax update panel on my easy responsive tab, so the page updates and stays on the tab.  Exactly what I needed.